# Query Netflix using OData API to get Genre and for a specific Language

Tags: odata, netflix

I am trying to use the Netflix OData API.
I wanted to query all English Movies that are of the Thriller Genre.

To get the list of the English Movies I use the following URL:
[http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Languages('English')/Titles?](http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Languages%28%27English%27%29/Titles?)

To get the list of Thrillers I use the following URL:
[http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Genres('Thrillers')/Titles?](http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Genres%28%27Thrillers%27%29/Titles?)

How would one query all English Movies that fall under the Thriller Genre?

Comment: OData is no more supported by NetFlix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need [Any/All](http://www.odata.org/blog/2011/2/15/even-more-any-and-all) query for OData in order to be able to filter results based on properties of a related collection. Any/All is supported in v3 of the protocol but unfortunately Netflix service doesn't support Any/All queries.